# Connection error after update mysql value C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, authentication

so my idea was once user will be loged in it will add +1 to the other table and online value in my mysql. I have done code like it's bellow. Once I have debug. I have inserted username and password but once I have press login button it says Error Connection. I am sure I have did something wrong in code but cant get it sort. So am trying to get help from you guys. Thanks

```
        private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtUsername.Text != "" && txtPassword.Text != "")
                {

                    con.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT id,username,password,email,fullname,company,uploads,avatar,account_type FROM users WHERE username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND password ='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
                    MySqlDataReader row;
                    row = con.ExecuteReader(query);
                    if (row.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (row.Read())
                        {
                            Properties.Settings.Default.username = row["username"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.email = row["email"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.fullname = row["fullname"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.company = row["company"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.uploads = row["uploads"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.user_avatar = row["avatar"].ToString();

                            MySqlCommand newcmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE company SET online = online + 1 WHERE name = '" + row["company"].ToString() + "'");

                            try
                            {
                                newcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (MySqlException ex)
                            {
                                con.Close();
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Number.ToString() + " -> " + ex.Message.ToString());
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        this.Hide();
                        dashboard dash = new dashboard();
                        dash.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Nie znaleziono użytkownika", "Information");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nazwa użytkownika lub hasło jest nie poprawne", "Information");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Błąd połączenia", "Information");
            }
```

Comment: what is the exception and in which line you are getting it?

Answer (score 1):

For your question, you have connection error when you log in.

The error may be that there is already an open data reader associated with this connection

which must be closed, so close the data reader connection.

You could try the following code to get it.

```
     private void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                if (txtUsername.Text != "" && txtPassword.Text != "")
                {


                    string query = "SELECT id,username,password,email,fullname,company,uploads,avatar,account_type FROM users WHERE username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND password ='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    MySqlDataReader row;
                    row = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    string company=null;
                    if (row.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (row.Read())
                        {
                            Properties.Settings.Default.username = row["username"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.email = row["email"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.fullname = row["fullname"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.company = row["company"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.uploads = row["uploads"].ToString();
                            Properties.Settings.Default.user_avatar = row["avatar"].ToString();
                            company = row["company"].ToString();

                            MessageBox.Show(row["company"].ToString(), "Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        row.Close();
                            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE company SET online = online + 1 WHERE name = '" + company + "'";
                            try
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (MySqlException ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Number.ToString() + " -> " + ex.Message.ToString());
                            }                
                        this.Hide();
                        dashboard dash = new dashboard();
                        dash.Show();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Nie znaleziono użytkownika", "Information");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nazwa użytkownika lub hasło jest nie poprawne", "Information");
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Błąd połączenia", "Information");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
       }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con); - Says can not convert to MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection from Database (where is general connection to database)

Comment: Based on the error information you provided, I can't reproduce your error message, so i'm not sure what's wrong with your code, provide me with detailed error reporting information so that I can better understand what the problem is.

Comment: MySqlCommand is trying to do query where it is selecting table from database call users which is this line ```string query = "SELECT id,username,password,email,fullname,company,uploads,avatar,account_type FROM users WHERE username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND password ='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";``` but new command can't open another connection? on line ```MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);```

Comment: Your problem may be MySQL database connection error. You can refer to the following website to write the connection statement.
Here is the link: [ https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ ], in this website, you can refer to the standard notation.